# Access global 'angular' in ionic2

Tags: angular, ionic2

I am trying to merge two object in ionic2 via angular.merge(Obj1,Obj2).
But I get error on save. How do I get access to the global angular object.

Here is the code I am using (from newApp\app\home.ts)

```
syncWithPortfolio(data){
  var ptfoliObject = this.portfolioObject;
  if(data){
      for(var x in data){
          angular.merge(ptfoliObject[x],data[x]);
      }
  }
```

The error on console:
"newApp/app/pages/home/home.ts(181,15): Error TS2304: Cannot find name 'angular'."

Thanks

Comment: Ionic 2 is built Angular 2, but your code seems to be Angular 1 that's why its not working.

Comment: I just wanna merge two object in Ionic2, How do I do that ?

Comment: try this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/171251/how-can-i-merge-properties-of-two-javascript-objects-dynamically, since IONIC 2 is also regular javascript. you might work with it

Comment: I am already working on alternatives. I just want to know, how to access the good old angular.merge  in ionic2.

Comment: in package.json, you need to add Angular 1.*, then do npm install & load them in app.ts. But I highly NOT recommend doing this, If you want to use merge, sort, filter, find etc such kind of functions then its best to use LODASH library.

Comment: Yeah, that is too much of overhead to access 'angular'. I will stick with alternative mentioned below in answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The approach is to leverage what is provided by JavaScript itself. In your case, `[Object.assign][1]`. Here is a sample:

```
syncWithPortfolio(data){
  var ptfoliObject = this.portfolioObject;
  if(data){
    for(var x in data){
      Object.assign(ptfoliObject[x], data[x]);
    }
  }
}
```